# Getting a list of conversations with Entity Framework and linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am looking for a good way of getting a list of recent conversations.

I have made an inbox ui, where I am looking to implement a proper way of getting a list of conversations.

I have the following tables set up, with a relation to the `Message` table

```
  public class Message
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }
      public string UserId { get; set; }
      public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

      public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
      public List<MessageReceived> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
      public List<MessageSent> MessagesSent { get; set; }
  }

  public class MessageReceived
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int MessageId { get; set; }
      public virtual Message Message { get; set; }

      public string FromUserId { get; set; }
      public ApplicationUser FromUser { get; set; }

      public string ToUserId { get; set; }
      public ApplicationUser ToUser { get; set; }

      public DateTime DateRecieved { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateRead { get; set; }
      public bool Deleted { get; set; }
  }
```

And for now i have this in my controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
      var messages = db.MessageReceived.Where(p => p.ToUserId == userId).GroupBy(p => p.FromUser.UserName);
      return View(messages);
  }
```

This will return the list of Usernames that the user has received a message from, including all the rows that are created when receiving a message. Which is not what I am aiming for. It could end bad when querying for multiple long conversations

Is there a more efficient way to query the list of conversations, than using group by?

Comment: So just to clarify: Are you looking for a list of usernames or a list of messages? It might also help if you post your View.

Comment: Sorry its a list of conversations with a username highlighted :)

Comment: Does "list of conversations" mean "list of all related messages both send and received by certain users"? Are you trying to join list of sent messages against list of received messages with provided user ID pair (e.g. A & B talking each other)?

Comment: Typo: it's **receive** (not "recieve" as you kept using over and over again)

Comment: As it is right now, i have an inbox with a list of conversations.

An example
conversations:

username one  (3 new messages)
username two (2 new messages) 
and so on

Answer (score 0):

If all you need are the list of names that a user has received messages from, a more efficient way to query this is:

```
var names = db.MessageRecieved.Where(p => p.ToUserId == userId).Select(p => p.FromUser.UserName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: So this will skip all duplicated items on database level ? It will not read 10* username and afterwards skip the 9 in memory? - Hope you understand what i mean